# Using directory in grails url mappings

Tags: java, model-view-controller, grails, groovy

I'm new to Grails, and formerly used Codeigniter for web application development.

I want to know if it's possible to map my url and controllers in a way like this.

So I have a folder in controllers called dashboard, in dashboard I have controllers like: users, groups, settings

So the setup in controllers or project.dashboard is

```
project.dashboard/Groups.groovy
```

I want corresponding views like this:

```
views/dashboard/groups/index.gsp
```

How would I use the URL mapping to set that up, this is what I have no which isn't working for me.

```
"/dashboard/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out

Comment: Why don't you put an answer to share your solution? :)

Comment: I'd love to see an answer too ;)

Comment: @lucke84 see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want subfolders inside `controllers`, that is effectively a change on the package your controller classes.

If you create a controller on `grails-app/controllers/dashboard/GroupsController.groovy`, the class belongs to the `dashboard` package:

```
package dashboard

class GroupsController {
  // ...
}
```

Adding extra folders in the views does not make much sense, the folders on `grails-app/views` are all-lowercase versions of the names of the controllers (eg. "groups" contains the views of "GroupsController"):

```
$ ls grails-app/views
groups/    layouts/    tasks/    users/
```